# What is the meaning of "The first rocket flamed to Heaven"?

Tags: meaning, agatha-christie, hercule-poirot

From Agatha Christie's 'Peril at End House', Chapter 7 (emphasis mine):

> Presently we all moved out into the garden to a place overlooking the sea and the harbour. A few chairs had been placed there for the elderly people, but most of us stood. **The first rocket flamed to Heaven.**

What is meant by this sentence?

I would guess this is referring to a plant(s), the obvious being some variant of [Rocket](https://www.rhs.org.uk/vegetables/rocket/grow-your-own). However, I can't find any explanation of something 'flaming to Heaven', specific to plants, or anything else for that matter. I suppose it could refer to flowers opening up in the morning?

Comment: "flaming to heaven" relates to seeing the fiery plume that the rocket makes as it takes off into the sky

Comment: Wow, I've been speaking English, not fluently or well but almost adequately, for several decades now, and I didn't know "rocket" was the name of a plant. Still, in interpreting this particular passage, I find it hard to understand why you'd go with the plant rather than one of those fiery things that shoots up into the sky.

Comment: @user14111 If you speak primarily American English, the equivalent is arugula. Rocket is the British English term for the same plant.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

They're watching fireworks.

A few paragraphs earlier we have the sentence: "‘It’s warm,’ said Nick. ‘It’ll be nice when we’re watching the fireworks.‘"

From the [*Merriam-Webster Dictionary*](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/rocket):

> **rocket:** a firework consisting of a case partly filled with a combustible composition fastened to a guiding stick and propelled through the air by the rearward discharge of the gases liberated by combustion.